# React Native + Redux: What's the best and preferred navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, react-native, redux

I would like to use Redux for React Native. Currently I have no set data management, so the index.ios.js has the following:

```
  renderScene(route, navigator){
    this._navigator = navigator

    return (
        <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
    )
  }

<Navigator
  configureScene={this.configureScene}
  initialRoute={{name: 'Login', component: Login}}
  renderScene={(route, navigator) => this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
  style={styles.container}
  navigationBar={
    <Navigator.NavigationBar
      style={styles.navBar}
      routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
    />
  }
/>
```

I am planning to switch to Redux. With my current set up, not using any frameworks, only exception being react-router, what would be the most preferred way to navigate using Redux? A sample using store, reducers, and actions would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You should look into NavigatorExperimental which support reducers. Existing Navigator is being depreciated. https://medium.com/@dabit3/first-look-react-native-navigator-experimental-9a7cf39a615b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: react-navigation should be used now instead of NavigationExperimental.

--

I advise you use NavigationExperimental instead of Navigator. The last is depreciated. There is an example in the RN documentation, [right here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html). It uses simple reducers to manage your navigation state. But you can also handle this state with Redux since it is the same logic.

**This is my setup with tabs, using Redux and NavigationExperimental:**

*navigator.js (note: the renderOverlay prop in CardStack will be renamed renderHeader in [0.32](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases))*

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { pop, push, selectTab } from './actions';

const {
  CardStack: NavigationCardStack,
} = NavigationExperimental;

class Navigator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._renderHeader = this._renderHeader.bind(this);
    this._renderScene = this._renderScene.bind(this);
  }

  _renderHeader(sceneProps) {
    return (
      <MyHeader
        {...sceneProps}
        navigate={this.props.navigate}
      />
    );
  }

  _renderScene(sceneProps) {
    return (
      <MyScene
        {...sceneProps}
        navigate={this.props.navigate}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { appNavigationState: { scenes, tabKey, tabs } } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <NavigationCardStack
          key={`stack_${tabKey}`}
          navigationState={scenes}
          renderOverlay={this._renderHeader}
          renderScene={this._renderScene}
        />
        <Tabs
          navigationState={tabs}
          navigate={this.props.navigate}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const getCurrentNavigation = (navigation) => {
  const tabs = navigation.tabs;
  const tabKey = tabs.routes[tabs.index].key;
  const scenes = navigation[tabKey];
  return {
    scenes,
    tabKey,
    tabs,
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    appNavigationState: getCurrentNavigation(state.navigation),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    navigate: (action) => {
      if (action.type === 'pop') {
        dispatch(pop());
      } else if (action.type === 'push' && action.route) {
        dispatch(push(action.route));
      } else if (action.type === 'tab' && action.tabKey) {
        dispatch(selectTab(action.tabKey));
      }
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Navigator);
```

*actions.js*

```
export function pop() {
  return ({
    type: 'POP_ROUTE',
  });
}

export function push(route) {
  return ({
    type: 'PUSH_ROUTE',
    route,
  });
}

export function selectTab(tabKey) {
  return ({
    type: 'SELECT_TAB',
    tabKey,
  });
}
```

*reducer.js (**note: I use immutable here, but it's up to you to use whatever fit you**)*

```
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native';
import { Record } from 'immutable';

const {
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils,
} = NavigationExperimental;


export const InitialState = Record({
  // Tabs
  tabs: {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'tab1' },
      { key: 'tab2' },
      { key: 'tab3' },
    ],
  },
  // Scenes
  tab1: {
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ key: 'tab1' }],
  },
  tab2: {
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ key: 'tab2' }],
  },
  tab3: {
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ key: 'tab3' }],
  },
});
const initialState = new InitialState();


export default function navigation(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POP_ROUTE': {
      const tabs = state.get('tabs');
      const tabKey = tabs.routes[tabs.index].key;
      const scenes = state.get(tabKey);
      const nextScenes = NavigationStateUtils.pop(scenes);

      if (scenes !== nextScenes) {
        return state.set(tabKey, nextScenes);
      }
      return state;
    }

    case 'PUSH_ROUTE': {
      const route = action.route;
      const tabs = state.get('tabs');
      const tabKey = tabs.routes[tabs.index].key;
      const scenes = state.get(tabKey);
      const nextScenes = NavigationStateUtils.push(scenes, route);

      if (scenes !== nextScenes) {
        return state.set(tabKey, nextScenes);
      }
      return state;
    }

    case 'SELECT_TAB': {
      const tabKey = action.tabKey;
      const tabs = state.get('tabs');
      const nextTabs = NavigationStateUtils.jumpTo(tabs, tabKey);

      if (nextTabs !== tabs) {
        return state.set('tabs', nextTabs);
      }
      return state;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Finally, in *MyScene.js* component you can simply handle the component to show by testing the current route (with a switch for example).
By passing the *navigate* function in your components, you can manage your scenes (ie: this.props.navigate({ type: 'push', route: { key: 'search' } })).

Notice that you can handle your state and your actions as you wish. The main idea to understand is how the state is reduced, regardless you use redux or not.

Comment: Really appreciate it! But I am looking to implement a navigationBar. So where should I do so and how can I? With the back button etc. Thank you in advance Yupichaks!

Comment: Also do I have to define each route individually or could I do something like the following: `<route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}/>`?

Comment: The _MyHeader_ component in my example is the navigation bar. NavigationExperimental includes a Header and a Title component :)
[See this gist](https://gist.github.com/yspychala/f6d685751abca41c6dc291d5333c97a1)

About your second question, I didn't test this way. You should try and see what fits you best.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! For the navigation bar, how would I implement left and right buttons, and style it individually? Also Header: NavigationHeader was deconstructed but NavigationHeader is continued to be referenced. Was that the intention?

Comment: @JoKo If you check the [NavigationHeader component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/38979f9c68bd054aca3c6102635b2005914506b1/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationHeader.js) you can see there is _renderLeftComponent_, _renderRightComponent_ and _renderTitleComponent_ props. By default a back button is implemented (and is styled depending on the platform). If you push a route it'll appear automatically. But you can put your own left or right component using this props if you want.

Comment: @Joko About the destructuring, I import the Header component from NavigationExperimental and name it NavigationHeader for more clarity. But you can also do `const { Header } = NavigationExperimental`. The result will be the same.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! I am still confused as to how to properly set up the `NavigationHeader`. Could you show a sample with the left button, title, and right button with default back button?

Comment: @Joko In the gist I sent you ([here](https://gist.github.com/yspychala/f6d685751abca41c6dc291d5333c97a1), you don't have to set manually the left button. A default back button will be added. But you can set your own custom button if you want, using renderLeftComponent, or add a right component like this : `renderRightComponent={() => <View><Text>right button</Text></View>}`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) for native and web environment it will [replace NavigationExperimental](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/08dbc43fa64ff1dfc0d364b6cef6262426f76b64) just take a look the following [example](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/ReduxExample).

- Components built for iOS and Android
- Share navigation logic between mobile apps, web apps, and server rendering.
- [Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/) is pretty straightforward
- Develop your own [navigation views](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/)
- It is easy!

Just define your navigation in your app.

```
import {
  TabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const BasicApp = TabNavigator({
  Main: {screen: MainScreen},
  Setup: {screen: SetupScreen},
});
```

...and navigate

```
class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    label: 'Home',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Setup Tab"
        onPress={() => navigate('Setup')}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And do the following in order to add [redux](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) just define your reducer...

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(AppRouteConfigs);

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: (state, action) => (
    AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state)
  )
});
```

...and navigate in your component with `addNavigationHelpers`

```
  <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
    dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
    state: this.props.nav,
  })} />
```