# How would you implement React Native's NavigationExperimental using Redux and Immutablejs?

Tags: react-native, redux, immutable.js

It seems NavigationExperimental is using it's own NavigationScenesReducer.js internally, requiring your Redux state tree to be a vanilla javascript object. Now my state is an Immutable Map and I don't understand how I would implement this when NavigationScenesReducer.js is used under the hood with NavigationExperimental.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example with NavigationExperimental, Redux and Immutable here : [React Native + Redux: What's the best and preferred navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842045/react-native-redux-whats-the-best-and-preferred-navigation/38847285#38847285)

Answer (score 0):

You can call toJS method of Immutable.js to convert it into a vanilla object.

NavigationExperimental doesn't specify on how you should be maintaining your state overall. Only it's navigationState property expects it to be of NavigationState type:

{
   index: -1,
   key: 'root',
   routes: [{key:"key"}]
  }

You can convert your state into navigationState format expected by NavigationExperimental before passing down to  navigationState property.